# How to copy by reference, only some elements of a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Supoose I have a python list `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`. now I neeed to make a list `b` such that `b` should contain elements `[1,2,3]`, but as a reference to `a`. By this I mean that if I change `a[1] = 3` then `b[0]` should alsoe be `3`. How shall I achieve this?

from what I know, with `b = a` I can have copy by reference, but only possible with full list, and if I do  `b = a[1:4]`, then its a seperate copy.

Comment: Using a NumPy array you can do this easily, as slicing returns a view there instead of shallow copy. There's [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) type in Python, but it is only limited to objects that support buffer.

Comment: The list contains custom made objects. so numpy wont work

Comment: That doesn't matter, slicing will still work. NumPy will simply use dtype=object if you throw in random objects.